# Como selecionar arquivos específicos em uma pasta?

Tags: c#, .net

Estou fazendo um Console Application em C# que, dado um array de nomes de arquivos ele retorna o endereço de cada um e os adiciona a um ZipFile do DotNetZip.

Atualmente eu código se encontra assim:

```
string[] nomes = { 
  "C:\\users\\fabio\\desktop\\pastateste\\teste1.txt",
  "C:\\users\\fabio\\desktop\\pastateste\\teste5.txt",
  "C:\\users\\fabio\\desktop\\pastateste\\teste6.txt",
  "C:\\users\\fabio\\desktop\\pastateste\\teste10.txt"};

            using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                foreach (string item in nomes)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(item))
                        zip.AddFile(item, "arquivos"); 
                }
                zip.Save("C:\\users\\fabio\\desktop\\compactteste.zip");
```

A pasta "pastateste" contém arquivos .txt do 1 ao 10 e eu só seleciono {1,5,6,10}, porém passando o endereço completo de cada arquivo no array nomes.

Como eu posso vasculhar a pasta "pastateste", pegar o endereço dos
arquivos testes{1,5,6,10} e armazená-los em outro array?

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath` pode ser o que você procura

Comment: Acredito que utilizando os métodos da biblioteca System.IO você consegue, olhe as classes File e Directory. Para listar os arquivos de um diretório você pode usar Directory.GetFiles()

Comment: Fabio, não dá pra entender o que você quer fazer efetivamente... Você consegue [edit] sua pergunta e tentar ser um pouco mais específico?

Comment: @LINQ Editado! Tentei ser mais claro agora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É bem simples. Você pode simplesmente obter todos os arquivos de "pastateste" e aplicar na coleção retornada um filtro usando o [**`Where`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) do LINQ.

No exemplo abaixo é feito o filtro dos arquivos usando uma regex que tenta encontrar pelo seguinte padrão:

- o nome do arquivo precisa conter a palavra "**teste**";
- depois precisa encontrar o número 1, 5, 6 ou 10;
- depois precisa encontrar a palavra "**.txt"**; e
- a string precisa finalizar depois disto

```
const string caminhoBase = @"C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\pastateste";
var regexArquivo = new Regex("teste(1|5|6|10).txt$");
    
var arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(caminhoBase).Where(a => regexArquivo.IsMatch(a));
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, obrigado. Caso o nome do arquivo fosse "arquivoteste1compactar.txt", o regex seria capaz de encontra-lo apenas com "teste(1).txt$" ?

Comment: @FabioHagiwara Neste caso precisa adaptar um pouco a expressão regular para aceitar qualquer string no início e entre `teste1` e `.txt`. Seria algo como: `(\S)*teste1(\S)*\.txt$`. Mas precisa de mais detalhes pra responder casando todos os casos, porque este padrão reconheceria a string `teste1.txt`, por exemplo.